# capturing project/product whiteboard: recommendation webcam + webapp solution

Tags: project-management, agile, scrum, agile-project-management, kanban

We are doing kanban and have a whiteboard with colored stickers. As sometimes the team is distributed (like home office) we need to have another visual access to that board. We want to do this with stationary webcam everybody can access.

Our requirements:

- good quality picture
- making stickers notes readable (description etc.), either by physical zoom or enlarging parts through high resolution
- access to the camera by browser-webapp, alternatively instant-messaging
- hardware/software setup compatible with linux OS

Did somebody of you setup such a thing? What are your lessons learned?

Having a physical wall with real notes is important. Going for another project-management webapplication is not an option for us.

Comment: I have the same question! Tired MS LifeCam Cinema - works OK if you got it close to the whiteboard

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using an electronic story board? I know it's not as good as the real deal, but with a distributed team that's the only viable option I think.

A good post about that:
http://agiletools.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/task-boards-telling-a-compelling-agile-story/

(middle to end of the page)

Comment: +1 for the link. but as said electronic taskboard is not an option for us. we are not "completely" distributed (most often in the office) so we want to combine physical (whiteboard) with electronic support (webcam).

Comment: Alternatively, you could just project or display the electronic task board wherever you need it.